# How to disable 3D building view in maps using HEREMAPS in react?

Tags: here-maps-rest

```
    const initMap = React.useCallback(defaultLayers => {
    let lat = -6;
    let lng = 100;
    let zoom = 20;

    areaMapRef.current = new window.H.Map(
      mapContainerRef.current,
      defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
      {
        zoom,
        center: { lng, lat }
      }
    );

    window.addEventListener("resize", areaMapRef.current.getViewPort().resize);

    behaviourRef.current = new window.H.mapevents.Behavior(
      new window.H.mapevents.MapEvents(areaMapRef.current)
    );

    uiRef.current = window.H.ui.UI.createDefault(
      areaMapRef.current,
      defaultLayers
    );
      }, []);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    const platform = new window.H.service.Platform({
    apikey: "MYAPIKEY"
    });
    const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
    initMap(defaultLayers);}, 
[initMap]);
```